# F# domain modelling with shared properties

Tags: f#

I can't figure out how to do the following in idiomatic F# (slightly adjusted for clarity):

```
type Shared(name, label, multivalue) = 
  member val Name = name with get, set
  member val Label = label with get, set
  member val Multivalue = multivalue with get, set

type TextField(name, label, multivalue) = 
  inherit Shared(name, label, multivalue)
  member val Xslt = "" with get, set

type NumberField(name, label, multivalue) = 
  inherit Shared(name, label, multivalue)        

// helper 'create' function  
let textfield name label =
  TextField (name, label, false)

// helper 'create'  function
let numberfield name label = 
  NumberField (name, label, false)

let makemultivaluefield (field: Shared)  = 
  field.Multivalue <- true
  //field <- I would want this to return the parent type. E.g. TextField or NumberField    

// Actual code for creating / using above domain (DSL like syntax... that's the goal of this whole exercise)
let myTextField = 
  textfield "field" "field"
  |> makemultivaluefield

let myNumberField = 
  numberfield "fieldnumber" "field number label"
  |> makemultivaluefield
```

The `|> makemultivaluefield` call returns a `unit` now, but I want it to return a `TextField` or a `NumberField`
(There are more classes like `NumberField` and `TextField` all with the same 3 properties declared in `Shared`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach with a minimal amount of change compared to your example would be something like this

```
let makemultivaluefield<'subtype when 'subtype :> Shared> (field: 'subtype) : 'subtype = 
  field.Multivalue <- true
  field
```

Make the function generic and then restrict it to subtypes of your `Shared` type. This should work fine for you unless your real life code is way more complex than the example.

Comment: Do we need the explicit type argument when we could use a flexible type as type parameter on the argument? `let makemultivaluefield (field: #Shared) = ...` infers as `val makemultivaluefield : field:'a -> 'a when 'a :> Shared`

Comment: True, you don't need that. These approaches are technically equivalent.